# Making decision for unanswered policy question

Tags: discussion, beta-sites

At the Health Stack Exchange, [I asked a question about the scope of the site](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/questions-about-animal-health?noredirect=1) (does it cover animal health or just human health?) and nobody ever answered. What happens next? Does this mean I am free to make a decision, post and accept it as an answer, and it becomes policy? Or just start posting questions about animal health and then if anyone complains we can take it up on Meta? I don't know how these decisions are made if nobody gets involved in the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hehe nice try.

A unilateral decision is usually a decision that never happens unless *enforced*, but that can't be unilateral since we get no choice... On the serious side, you can't represent or make any policy by yourself. Any Stack Exchange site is a democracy with most powers given to *elected* moderators who also help maintain and solve questions about the site. The discussion has probably hasn't seen much attention (only 30 views).

Thus, to get someone involved, you can:

- Flag the question for a moderator to view (most appropriate solution really)

and if you really need to:

- Ask someone in chat to look at the question
- Edit the question to bump the question up

Decisions (answers) are also voted upon by users so their voice can be heard too. So if you post an answer, don't expect it to be policy immediately. You have to wait to hear the voices of the other users too and of course, the moderators. Once there is a highly voted answer that stands out from the rest (probably at least a score of 8 in my opinion), you can accept it that answer and it becomes "policy".